# Как сделать точки в css

Tags: css, border

Как сделать такие точки?
Я пробовал border dotted, но они слишком близко друг к другу..

```
<div class="icon-fifth-block">
                        <div class="icon-fifth-block-left">
                          <span class="icon-fifth-block-left__date"
                            >2 ИЮНЯ / ДЮРСО</span
                          >
                          <div class="icon-fifth-block-left__block">
                            <div class="icon-fifth-block-left__block-title">
                              БАЗОВЫЙ <br />
                              ОДИН ДЕНЬ
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon-fifth-block-left__block-subtitle">
                              КЕМПИНГ / 1 МАСТЕР-КЛАСС / 1 КВЕСТ
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon-fifth-block-left__block-rent">
                              *ВОЗМОЖНА АРЕНДА ПАЛАТКИ
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="icon-fifth-line"></span>
                        <div class="icon-fifth-block-right">
                          <button class="button icon-fifth-block-right__button">
                            КУПИТЬ БИЛЕТ
                          </button>
                          <div class="icon-fifth-block-right__text">
                            ДО 30.05 — 1 000 руб
                          </div>
                          <div class="icon-fifth-block-right__text">
                            ДО 15.06 — 1 500 руб
                          </div>
                          <div class="icon-fifth-block-right__text">
                            ДО 2.07 — 2 000 руб
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Это не точки, это чёрточки. Попробуйте `dashed` вместо `dotted`

Comment: Стало лучше, но они все равно близко друг другу прилегают..

Comment: Для более тонкой настройки таких вещей придётся использовать `svg`. Добавьте в вопрос свой код, воспроизводящий проблему

Comment: Код добавил))))

Comment: При редактировании вопроса есть кнопка `Фрагмент кода на JavaScript/HTML/CSS Ctrl-M`. Добавьте сюда разметку и стили, воспроизводящие вашу проблему